# Upload file size limits to 256MB

Tags: assets, config, php, upload

I have run into a problem of file sizes maxing out on 256MB.

**On PHP side I have**
`upload_max_filesize` & `post_max_size` set to `1GB`

I've created a simple PHP script to test upload size and managed to upload 800MB file. So everything points to Craft having some limits.

**In Craft CMS config file I have:**

```
'maxUploadFileSize'     => 1073741824
```

Yet if I try to upload files larger than 256MB I get a modal message saying file size exceeds 256MB.

Answer (score 7):

When determining the maximum upload file size, Craft [first takes](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/variables/AppVariable.php#L209-L230) the php.ini file `upload_max_filesize`, `post_max_size` and `memory_limit` into account by getting the minimum value and only then applying the Craft [`maxUploadFileSize`](https://craftcms.com/docs/config-settings#maxUploadFileSize) config setting.

Comment: Is this still true for Craft 3? Does Craft always read the entire file into memory when uploading?

Comment: Yes. Just ran into this on a new site. memory_limit was set to 256, and that was the deciding factor in file size upload limit.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, Craft requires `memory_limit` to also be set to max value, so setting `memory_limit` in `php.ini` did solve my problem.